# Chrome extension, get headers of current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, response-headers

I know `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` but it gives me only headers from request executed by my extension.

Instead of doing another request in background, I would like to get headers of my selected tab from chrome.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You'll need to reload the tab.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chrome.webRequest` APIs observe all HTTP requests that your extension has permissions for, not just ones made by your extension.

If you're not seeing the requests you expect to see, one of the following may be the case:

1. The extension is being loaded (or installed) after the page has already loaded. The Web Request API can only observe requests that are currently occurring, not ones that occurred in the past.
2. Your extension doesn't have permissions for the page. Give it permissions.
3. You are trying to observe requests made by a protected page, like the Chrome Web Store. You can't do that.

Comment: Thank you Duskwuff, you are right, I can log all allowed requests from chrome with my extension with this listener.
I can use `type == 'main_frame'` and `tabId` do get my headers of my current page load :) it works like a charm.